# Graphql mutation returning null, but database is updated

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I'm trying to add a mutation to allow for the client to add a document to the LineItem schema. The code I've written below allows me to do that when I test it using GraphiQL, but the response I get is null. How do I fix the code so that the response is the new document?

```
addLineItem: {
    type: LineItemType,
    args: {
      orderId: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
      productId: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)},
      quantity: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)}
    },
    resolve(parent, args) {
      Product.findById(args.productId, (err, result) => {
        let price = result.price;
        let subtotal = price*args.quantity;
        let lineitem = new LineItem({
          orderId : args.orderId,
          productId : args.productId,
          quantity : args.quantity,
          subtotal: subtotal
        });
        return lineitem.save();
    }}
  }
},
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning any value in `resolve` function, the `lineitem.save();` returns the value inside the `callBack`

make resolve function `async`, remove the `findById` callBack and await for the result, then implement your logic and return the value, like below:

```
async resolve(parent, args) {
  const result = await Product.findById(args.productId);

  let price = result.price;
  let subtotal = price*args.quantity;
  let lineitem = new LineItem({
    orderId : args.orderId,
    productId : args.productId,
    quantity : args.quantity,
    subtotal: subtotal
  });

  return lineitem.save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your code . .

You need to specify a return value as a type `(e.g. Boolean, String, etc)`. Types can be nullable, for example:  the value can be null, and, in fact, they are nullable by default **unless you define them with !**

so there is nothing wrong with null return value.